# how to use iif with lookup in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services

I have researched and not been able to find the answer to my question. My goal is to use the Lookup function in SSRS, which is currently performing as intended. However, I have null values that are not present which I would represented as '0'. It seems like I should be able to use the Lookup expression along with a IIF function. However, I cannot find an example of this. Any ideas how I can accomplish this? My Lookup expression is below.

Comment: You did not show your current expression.